# Split the CSV file using SSIS to SQL Database tables

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I have a CSV file with some 30 columns and I want to process it and put the data into two separate tables(Header, Body tables) that are linking with foreign key.
I have a data like

```
Batch HeaderName HeaderValue TailNum TailValue 
0001    abc         xyz       sdfs     dfgd
0001    abc         xyz        sdf     sdfs
0002    sadf        sdfsd      sdfsd    sfsdf
```

I want to dump this data to 
Header table

```
Id   Batch    HeaderName    HeaderValue
1     0001     abc             xyz
2     0002     sadf            sdfsd
```

Body table

```
Id   HeaderId(Foreign Key)   TailName    TailValue
1      1                      sdfs          dfgd
2      1                      sdf           sdfs
3      2                      sdfsd         sfsdf
```

I want to split this data and then dump data into tables in Data Integration.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem. Then the solution is quite simple. Just use a Multicast to duplicate your data and then aggregate each path. You can configure how to aggregate the data and use this to get the expected output for each table. I will give you a picture of the structure, do not panic due to all the mistakes, I did not configure all of this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but In Table2 I need to include the (Primary key Id) of the Table1. If you see my data in my body table I am including HeaderId